# Created model in CNN doesnt give the expected result

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I have created model dogs and cats classifier using CNN using tensorflow.Its accuracy is around 90% and validation accuracy is 80%.But when I input my own downloaded images of cats and dogs it gives wrong results.I make sure that the input images are of the same size as that when used in training.

Comment: put your code content

Answer (score 0):

Your AI classifier is overfitting and need to be fixed that first.
Try out:

- add more layers to the network
- [different learning rates](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understand-the-dynamics-of-learning-rate-on-deep-learning-neural-networks/)
- [add drop out](http://laid.delanover.com/dropout-explained-and-implementation-in-tensorflow/)
- [add batch normalization](https://machinelearningmastery.com/batch-normalization-for-training-of-deep-neural-networks/)

**Note:** For a classifier to work better at the inferencing time(test time) there should be some training examples **similar** to that of examples you are going to test the classifier.

For example: Suppose you have trained your classifier with the images of dogs and cats but if you are testing your trained classifier with the **cartoon images of dogs and cats** then your classifier will probably fail in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems when I started some tutorial. Please check that you have the same color channels (like RGB). In my case the training and validation set had other color channels than the images I downloaded.